# SQL count regex matches (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, count

I would like to count the regex instances from a table. For example:

```
    message                    state
    ================================
    [foo] aaaa                 active
    [bar] aaaa                 idle
    [foo] bbbb                 idle
    [foo] cccc                 active
    [bar] dddd                 active
    [tar] eeee                 idle
```

What I would like to have is following:

```
    messageType               ocurrences
    ====================================
    [foo]                             3
    [bar]                             2
    [tar]                             1
```

Is there any way to do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a "regex instance"?

Comment: well, I mean more regex "matches". Thanks!

Comment: what about [this](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/counting-regexp-matches-with-mysql/4499)?

Comment: [`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE messageType ~ '[[]foo[]]';`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33420/7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count the first "word" in the message, then use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(message, ' ', 1) as messageType, count(*)
from table t
group by substring_index(message, ' ', 1)
order by count(*) desc;
```

EDIT:

You can do this in Postgres by looking for the first space:

```
select left(message, position(' ' in message) as messageType, count(*)
from table t
group by messageType
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I think this is a good hint, but I forgot to mention, that my database is PostgreSQL and substring_index is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

just like the response above but with Postgres version:

```
select regexp_matches(message, '\[.+\]') as messageType, count (*)
from table1
group by regexp_matches(message, '\[.+\]')
order by count (*) desc;
```