# Match count of a regular expression for every row

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I use below query to get content rows which has my_regex_pattern. But I don't know how many times the pattern hit for every row. What is the best way to get match count for every row in Postgres?

For example if a row's content is 'abcdefabcgh' and my regular expression is 'abc', I want 2 since 'abcdefabcgh' has two 'abc'.

```
SELECT content
FROM table1
WHERE content ~ 'my_regex_pattern'
```

Or how can I get rows which has matches more than a specific number. For example just give me records which has abc more than 4 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL count regex matches (PostgreSQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182160/sql-count-regex-matches-postgresql)

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate of an SO question but this is probably more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757194/postgresql-count-number-of-times-substring-occurs-in-text

Comment: I think regexp_matches instead of ~ solves my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can make it work with `regexp_matches()`. Or better yet, [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). To apply to a whole table, use a `LATERAL` join (requires Postgres 9.3+):

```
SELECT content, ct
FROM   table1 t, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) - 1 AS ct
   FROM   regexp_split_to_table(t.content, 'abc')
   ) c
WHERE  t.content ~ 'abc';  -- eliminate rows without match
```

For simple patterns like in the example in your question, you could also:

```
SELECT content, (length(content) - length(replace(content, 'abc', ''))) / length('abc')
FROM   table1
WHERE  content LIKE '%abc%';
```

Typically faster, since regular expression functions are costly. Also works for older versions.